# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, sql

```
SignupClass.SqlBağlama.Open();
SqlDataAdapter adtr = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from LibraryBooksTable", SignupClass.SqlBağlama);
DataSet dtset = new DataSet();
adtr.Fill(dtset, "LibraryBooksTable");

// error on next line
mainWindow.LibraryBooksDatagrid.ItemsSource = dtset.Tables["LibraryBooksTable"];

SignupClass.SqlBağlama.Close();
```

Why am I getting error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

?

Comment: You need _dtset.Tables["LibraryBooksTable"].AsEnumerable()_

Comment: `mainWindow.LibraryBooksDataGrid.ItemsSource` is expecting something that implements `IEnumerable` [which `DataTable` does not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0). You can call the [`AsEnumerable()` extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable?view=net-5.0) like so: `dtset.Tables["LibraryBooksTable"].AsEnumerable()`.